# Destination class in Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventHub.Models does not have properties to support Data Lake Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub

I am trying to create an EventHub with capture capability enabled. I am using 
EventHubManagementClient from Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventHub.

Azure portal allows to choose from two Capture Providers like Storage Account and Data Lake Storage. But when I try it with the client library the Destination class in Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventHub.Models does not have properties for to support Data Lake Storage.

```
 public class Destination{
      public Destination();
      public Destination(string name = null, string storageAccountResourceId = null, string 
      blobContainer = null, string archiveNameFormat = null);

      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string StorageAccountResourceId { get; set; }
      public string BlobContainer { get; set; }
      public string ArchiveNameFormat { get; set; }
}
```

Why is it not included here? Do I have to use a different client to achieve this?

Comment: can you create successfully just with storage account? I tried, but no good luck, hang there.

Comment: @IvanYang Yes, I was able to create it with storage account. But not with data lake storage.

Comment: can you share your code? thanks. I failed on this.

Comment: @IvanYang, refer this https://gist.github.com/BalaSubramaniamMurugeshan/305d5dd2baf5a04e01377381d33a6f6a

Comment: thanks very much :)

Comment: @IvanYang you are welcome, please feel free to upvote my question

Comment: yeah, I just upvoted.